# Select all expiring credit card dates from the mmyy column in mySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have a column called cc_expire in mySQL with entries of the format mmyy, how can I select / query only the records for which the mmyy value equals next month?

So for example, if our current mmyy = 0618, I want to return all the entries of 0718 and higher.

Also, how would I account for the next year, as in mmyy = 1218, as the records returned should be equal to 0119 and higher?

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you store other credit card details in plain text?

Comment: No, just the expiry date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to build a bona fide date out of your `cc_expire` column.  We can do this by assuming each date is arbitrarily the first of that month.  Then, compare each credit card record against the first of the following month.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01', cc_expire), '%d%m%Y') >=
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01');
```

### Demo

Note: This answers your question, but it would much better long term if you would store proper dates for the credit card expiration dates.

Comment: Brilliant! I tried fiddling with those but couldn't get the logic in my head sorted out properly, it seems. Thank you!

Comment: @CrazySerb Consider storing actual expiration dates instead of just shortened versions, for future reference.

Comment: Yeah, that I don't have control over, and I have to work with whatever is in place right now... or rather around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query using the `CURDATE` [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_curdate.asp), `SUBSTRING` [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp) and `CONCAT` [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp).

For your first question, select the parts of the current date that you require:

```
WHERE cc_expire = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 5, 2), SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 2, 2))
```

For the second question, the date has to be disassembled and checked in two steps for the current year (month is relevant) and future years.

```
where SUBSTRING(cc_expire, 2, 2) > SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 2, 2)  # year is larger
    OR (SUBSTRING(cc_expire, 2, 2) = SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 2, 2)  # year is equal
        AND SUBSTRING(cc_expire, 0, 2) > SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 5, 2))
```

Note that I explicitly disregard the problem that occurs due to the year being only 2 numbers (i.e.\@, `99 < 05`). Please check for your assumptions on this problem.